# Stacked histogram of grouped values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

i am trying to create a stacked histogram of grouped values using this code:

```
titanic.groupby('Survived').Age.hist(stacked=True)
```

But I am getting this histogram without stacked bars.

[image]

How can i get the histogram's bar stacked without having to use matplotlib directly or iterating over groups?

Dataset used: https://www.udacity.com/api/nodes/5454512672/supplemental_media/titanic-datacsv/download

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Improve the answer, the best way could be:

```
titanic.pivot(columns='Survived').Age.plot(kind = 'hist', stacked=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The best way that I found so far is to create a new dataframe with the groups:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Non-Survivors': titanic.groupby('Survived').get_group(0).Age,
              'Survivors':   titanic.groupby('Survived').get_group(1).Age})
            .plot.hist(stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: When grouping by columns with more values, this is probably easier: `pd.DataFrame({k: v for k, v in titanic.groupby('Survived').Age}).plot.hist(stacked=True)`

Comment: Best solution for me here, in particular as `df.pivot` is a very specific operation that only works for categorical serie.

Answer (score 5):

I defined a custom function that leverages `np.histogram`
Also note that the histogram groups are calculated within groups of `'Survived'`

```
def hist(x):
    h, e = np.histogram(x.dropna(), range=(0, 80))
    e = e.astype(int)
    return pd.Series(h, zip(e[:-1], e[1:]))

kw = dict(stacked=True, width=1, rot=45)
titanic.groupby('Survived').Age.apply(hist).unstack(0).plot.bar(**kw)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This solution uses a bar plot instead of a histogram but I think it gives you what you are looking for.

```
titanic.groupby(['Survived', pd.cut(titanic['Age'], np.arange(0,100,10))])\
       .size()\
       .unstack(0)\
       .plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]