# pandas .plot.hist() with .groupby()

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, pivot-table, histogram

I'm aware that [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622054/stacked-histogram-of-grouped-values-in-pandas) has been asked; however, I'm looking for further clarification to have better understanding of .groupby if it's possible.
[Data used](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/titanic.csv)

I want the exact same result like this but with .groupby():

```
df.pivot(columns='survived').age.plot.hist()
```

[image]

So I try:

```
df.groupby('age')['survived'].count().plot.hist()
```

[image]

The x-axis doesn't look right. Is there any way I can get the same result as .pivot() does using the pure .groupby() method? Thank you.

Comment: Somewhat equivalent would be `(df['survived'].groupby(pd.cut(df.age, bins=10))
   .value_counts()
   .unstack().plot.bar(width=0.4)
)`.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Quang's comment, you would want to bin the ages rather than grouping on every single age (which is what `df.groupby('age')` does).

One method is to [**`cut`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) the `age` bins:

```py
df['age group'] = pd.cut(df.age, bins=range(0, 100, 10), right=False)
```

Then `groupby` those bins and make a bar plot of the `survived.value_counts()`:

```py
(df.groupby('age group').survived.value_counts()
   .unstack().plot.bar(width=1, stacked=True))
```

I noticed that in the link you posted, all the histograms look a little different. I think that's due to slight differences in how each method is binned. One advantage of cutting your own bins is that you can clearly see the exact bin boundaries:

[image: histogram of survival by age]

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted this question because there's a very subtle difference between `pivot` and `groupby`. I think you're looking for something similar to this:

```
df.groupby('age').size().plot.bar(width=1)
plt.show()
```

However, I do not think there's a reasonable way to get the same result by grouping because `hist()` needs the observations in its raw form, while `groupby` is designed to be followed by a function that will transform the data (such as `count`, `min`, `mean`, etc.).

To see this, notice that by grouping by `age` and then using `count`, you no longer have the raw array of ages anymore. For instance, there are 13 observations of people who are 40 years of age. The raw data looks like `(40, 40, ... , 40, 40)`, while the grouped count looks like:

```
age  count
 40     13
```

This is not what the data should look like for a histogram. Another key difference are the bins in a histogram. As you can see, the first plot counts all the observations of people with ages between 0 and 10. By grouping by age, you would have 11 bins inside this bin: one for people aged 0, one for people aged 1, one for people aged 2, etc.

To summarize, `groupby` expects a function that will transform the original data, but in order to plot a histogram, you need the data in its crude state. For this reason, `pivot` is the go-to solution for this kind of task, as it also splits the data by `survived`, but does not apply any functions the data.